# Why iOS Facebook Signup Email id not returned in my account?

Tags: ios, facebook, email

I'm using `signup with Facebook`. Other `Facebook` login works fine. Some accounts are working fine, but some accounts are not returning `email`. If anyone knows the reason please help me!

```
- (void)facebookOpenSession{

NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_birthday",@"basic_info",@"user_location",@"user_likes",@"email",@"public_profile",@"user_hometown",@"user_about_me",nil];
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login
 logInWithReadPermissions: permissions
 fromViewController:self.view.window.rootViewController
 handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error) {
     } else if (result.isCancelled) {
     } else {
         if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
         {
             [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                                parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture, email,name,first_name,last_name"}]
              startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                  if (!error) {
                      if ([result objectForKey:@"email"]!=NULL)
                      {
                      [self newFbLoginFunction:result];
                      }
                  }
              }];
         }
     }
 }];}
```

Response like this:

```
{
"first_name" = AAAA;
id = 1XXXXXXXXX2258;
"last_name" = BBBBB;
name = "AAAA BBBBB";
picture =     {
    data =         {
        "is_silhouette" = 0;
        url = "https://fb-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/XXXXXXXXXXX3212_3395344935279367518_n.jpg?oh=7345e4de6XXXXXXXXXXXX8&oe=58E16A60&__gda__=14951668XXXXXXXXXX2bc0aec58eab3f25e47";
    };
};}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all users use an email to login, you can also use a phone number. Also, emails need to be approved by Facebook or they will not show up with the API.

In other words: You can never guarantee to get an email back. Present an email input field to the user if you can´t get the email with the API.

Comment: I'm signup with email only. I didn't login with any app.

Comment: "some account not returning email" - it´s about other users, not your user.